# When formatting to table ForEach statement not printing correct value

Tags: powershell

I am running a script in Powershell and am having trouble with one of my ForEach Statements.  I have two objects created that contain parsed elements from a JSON file.

```
#Store API results as variable
$json = Get-Content $OutputJsonFile -Raw  | ConvertFrom-Json

#Get list of executed synthetic monitors by name
$executedMonitors = $json.result.data.dimensionMap."dt.entity.synthetic_test.name"

#Get list of values from JSON file
$Values = $json.result.data.values
Write-Host "Values: " $Values
```

****This prints to console as: Values:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

I then am trying to add an additional 'property'? to each value of PASS/FAIL

```
#Check '$Values' object and if greater than or equal to 1 set PASS else set FAIL
$condition = '1'
ForEach($value in $Values) {
if ($value -ge $condition) {
    $value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName passFail -NotePropertyValue PASS
} else {
    $value | Add-Member -NotePropertyName passFail -NotePropertyValue FAIL
}
}
Write-Host "Values after pass/fail added: " $Values.passFail
```

***This prints to console: "Values after pass/fail added:  PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS FAIL"
*This is what is expected to print to the report object I am creating

I then would like to print both of those objects and format into a table

```
#Creates table listing Synthetic Monitors and Statuses retrieved from Data Explorer metrics
$Report = ForEach($executedMonitor in $executedMonitors) {
    $Results = '' | SELECT Application, Status
    $Results.Application = $executedMonitor
    foreach($value in $Values){
    $Results.Status = $value.passFail
    Write-Host "Results value: " $value.passFail
    }
    $Results
}
$Report | Format-Table -auto
```

**This prints the table with the correct '$executedMonitors', but prints the last value of the "$Values" object.

```
Application            Status
-----------            ------
A                       FAIL
B                       FAIL
C                       FAIL
D                       FAIL
E                       FAIL
F                       FAIL
G                       FAIL
H                       FAIL
I                       FAIL
J                       FAIL
K                       FAIL
L                       FAIL
```

*This is where I am experiencing the issue with my code.  It seems the forEach loop is iterating through the loop 13 times and using the last value of $Values object

I am very new to Powershell and cannot figure out why this forEach loop is failing for $Values

I have tried everything I can think of to change the foreach loop and am not understanding the logic being incorrect.  If possible I was thinking to have two separate arrays that can print to a table and be reformatted, but can not figure out how to do so.  I have also tried creating the $Values object as a hash table and got the same results.

Ultimately I need this table to be transformed to an HTML table to put into an email body.  Haven't thought about that step yet, because I cannot get my logic to work.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to enumerate the `$executedMonitors` and `$Values` arrays *in tandem*, i.e. as pairs of corresponding elements:

```bash
$i = 0
$report = 
  foreach ($executedMonitor in $executedMonitors) {
    '' | Select-Object Application, Status |
      ForEach-Object {
        $_.Application = $executedMonitor
        $_.Status = $Values[$i++].passFail
        $_ # Output the modified object.
      }
  }
```

PowerShell has no direct ability to enumerate multiple collections in tandem,<sup>[1]</sup> so the `$Values` array must be accessed *by index*.

Simpler **PowerShell v3+** solution:

```bash
$i = 0
$report = 
  foreach ($executedMonitor in $executedMonitors) {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Application = $executedMonitor
      Status = $Values[$i++].passFail
    }
  }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> $Report = foreach ($executedMonitor in $executedMonitors) {
>   $Results = '' | SELECT Application, Status
>   $Results.Application = $executedMonitor
>   foreach ($value in $Values){
>     $Results.Status = $value.passFail
>     Write-Host "Results value: " $value.passFail
>   }
> $Results
> ```

By *nesting* the `foreach($value in $Values)` loop inside the outer loop, you're in effect assigning the *same* value to `$Results.Status` in every iteration of the outer `$executedMonitors` loop, namely the *last* `$Values` element's `.passFail` property value.

---

<sup>[1] Enhancing the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statement was proposed in [GitHub issue #14732](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14732), but unfortunately rejected; the discussion has been somewhat rekindled by a near-duplicate request, [GitHub issue #20126](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20126).</sup>